# Refactoring. How extract code to a generic method?

Tags: java, generics, refactoring, simplify

To avoid duplication in the code, is there a way to extract to a separate method of the selected code?

```java
class Builder
{
    private final List< UnitIf > unit = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List< TimeIf > time = new ArrayList<>();

    public Builder withUnit( final UnitIf aUnit )
    {
        //Extract to method
        if( aUnit != null )
        {
            unit.add( aUnit );
        }
        return this;
        //----------------
    }

    public Builder withTime( final TimeIf aTime )
    {
        //Extract to method
        if( aTime != null )
        {
            time.add( aTime );
        }
        return this;
        //----------------
    }
}
```

My goal is to simplify the code by eliminating duplication. But the parts of code use different data types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a method

```
public <T> Builder addIfNonNull(List<T> dst, T x)
{
    if (x != null) {
        dst.add(x);
    }   
    return this;
}
```

and implement `withUnit` like

```
public Builder withUnit( final UnitIf aUnit )
{
    return addIfNonNull(unit, aUnit);
}
```

and change `withTime` the same way.

## Non-generic version

If you don't want it to be a generic method, just omit the type parameter `T` and change the type of `x` to be `Object`:

```
public Builder addIfNonNull(List dst, Object x)
{
    if (x != null) {
        dst.add(x);
    }   
    return this;
}
```

Internally, the Java compiler will compile `List<T>` to just `List`. I think it is called "type erasure".

Comment: It is very good solution for me. Is possible any solution without generic types?